# Open an UDP channel in java

Tags: java, sockets, datagram

I want to open an UDP channel between the Client and the server with UDP. I have two questions. When i write

```
DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(port);;
```

is the channel opened or it will be open when I start sending ?
and How can I specify the IP adress of the server ?

Comment: UDP does not have channels.

Comment: UDP is not like TCP, it is a connectionless protocol.  It is also an unreliable protocol so you must allow for the likely event that some packets will be lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(port);

Constructs a datagram socket and binds it to the specified port on the local host machine.

it does not create a channel between client and server.

> when the server starts to listen, client can send udp packet to this udp port number.

for example if you want to bind a udp socket to a specific ip and port number use below method

> bindAddress="192.148.1.0";
>
> DatagramSocket socket=new (bindPort,InetAddress.getByName(bindAddress));

Comment: So I have to specify the server adress in the packet ?

Comment: yes when you want to send packet to a specific udp port mention the server address and port number into DatagramPacket. thats

Answer (score 1):

I find information about it

Here is how you open a DatagramChannel:

```
   DatagramChannel channel = DatagramChannel.open();
   channel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(9999));
```

more infor here http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/datagram-channel.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following tutorial example for writing UDP client/servers in java. The IP address only needs to be specified by the client in order to connect to the server. However the port is needed by both parts.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/clientServer.html